# SQL select distinct based on a columns reference - Query Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I need to distinct a column but it based for an other column.

Here is an example

```
colA colB
---------
a   1 
a   1 
a   2 
a   3

b   1
b   2 
b   2 
b   4 

c   1
c   1 
c   2
c   2
```

Expected result

```
a   1 
a   2 
a   3

b   1
b   2 
b   4 

c   1
c   2
```

Anyone have an idea please on query mysql ? .

Thanks

Comment: Simply `SELECT DISTINCT`...

Comment: ohhhhh, I don't think the order of the distinct , thanks

Comment: If I have for example many columns, and I want just distinct for 2 columns only ?

Comment: Ask another question.

Comment: thanks, I already got the response I need , ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try '**Distinct**'. And if you want just distinct for 2 columns only try '**GROUP BY**'.
Here's Demo:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: @ALFA, if this works for you try giving this answer is useful thumbs up.

Comment: w3*ools is a really poor advice. Some many errors at that place.

Comment: @jarlh, it's a perfect place for beginner

Answer (score 1):

Just write `Select Distinct Column1, Column2 from Table`

Distinct will give you unique tuples, so unique combinations of your specified columns from the source set.

Comment: If I have for example many columns, and I want just distinct for 2 columns only ?

Comment: Just select from these two columns and dont mention the others. So if your table has Column1, Column2, Column 3 and Column4, Just say `Select Distinct Column1, Column2 from Table1` and you'll get a set of all unique combinations of Column1 and Column2. What is in Column3 and Column4 does not matter